# chaining http post and q service in angular in serial fashion

Tags: angularjs, promise, q

I have this code in angular,

```
    $http({
        method:'POST',
        url :'someURL',    //returns an array of urls [url1, url2, url3..]
        data : dataObj

    })
    .then(function(response) {
        var items = response.data;
        var promises = [];
        $scope.output =[];
        items.forEach(function(el){
            return promises.push($http.get(el)); //fills the promise[] array
        });

    var ignore = function(x) { return x.catch(function(){}); } // To ignore if promise does not get resolved (only accept responses with status 200)
    var all = $q.all( promises.map(ignore) ); //chaining promises array 
    all.then(function success(d){
        console.log($scope.output);  //want the output to be ["text1", "text2", "text3"...]
    });

    for (var i=0; i < promises.length ; i++){

        promises[i].then(success).catch(function (){
        });
        function success(r){
            $scope.output.push(r.data.text);   //{text: "text1"}
        }
    }
    });
```

The result of this operation is stored in `$scope.output`. On executing I'm getting output as `["text2", "text3", "text1" ...]` which is not in a serial fashion. My question is how I can make this execute in a serial fashion so that the output would be `["text1", "text2", "text3" ...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your last `for` loop with the following:

```
angular.forEach(promises, function(promise, index){
       promise.then(success).catch(function (){});
       function success(r){
           $scope.output[index] = r.data.text;
       }
});
```

Due to closure paradigm the `index` variable will be available in the `success` handler upon promise resolution no matter in which order the promises get resolved and the results will be placed to the `output` array in the order of the original promises.

Comment: Yeah, you should make use of closures to capture the index on each iteration. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test it, but from first view I'd say you need to put the for() loop inside the `all.then()`.

```
all.then(function success(d){
  console.log($scope.output);

  for (var i=0; i < promises.length ; i++) {
    promises[i].then(success).catch(function () { });

    function success (r) {
      $scope.output.push(r.data.text);
    }
  }
});
```

Because otherwise you loop through partially unresolved promises. Those that resolve earlier will skip ahead in the queue.

Having the for() loop inside the `all.then()` you make sure that all promises have resolved already and will add themselves to the output list  when they are called with `promises[i].then(success)`.

Comment: I tried your solution, still I'm getting the results out of order :(

Answer (score 0):

IMO,you should not use callbacks inside for loop. I think, it is causing this behavior. I hope it will work. No need to add last for loop.

```
var all = $q.all( promises.map(ignore) );
all.then(function success(d){
    d.forEach(function(res){
         $scope.output.push(r.data.text);
    });
    console.log($scope.output);  
});
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs, I tried the exact same thing, still I'm getting the result out of order and not in sequential :(